# How to do proper arrangement of columns having larger image than parent in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on my website development. While creating the portfolio page, I encountered the issue of the last column moving to next row.
I do have images larger than the parent container but I figured it out to display properly, however, after applying the margin the last column went to next row.
Please check the link below:

https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/o1e9d

I also wanted to add img-thumbnail class but it does not look proper and adding padding also didn't work as expected.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: The link is not accessible, pls use `JSFiddle` or `snippet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `margin: 1px` on bootstraps column class which breaks the last column.

Add another `div` inside `gallery_product` and apply `border/margin` to inner div.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I could add the margin.